# Data Migration - How to set Opportunity Closed Date in Past?

Tags: apex, data-loader, data-migration

I am doing a data migration from another CRM to Salesforce.  Some of the opportunities in the legacy system have a closed date in the past.  When I try to migrate those into salesforce, I get an error saying the close date can't be in the past.

I have already turned on the feature "Create Audit Fields", but this "seems" only works for the Created By, Updated By, Created Date, Last Modified Date.

Is there any way to import opportunities with close dates in the past so we can maintain accuracy for historical reasons?

Comment: That sounds like a Validation rule in the system. Unless I am seriously wrong, Salesforce does not have an OOTB restriction on opportunity close dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sebastian Kessel pointed out, this sounds like is probably due to an Opportunity validation rule of some other customization an Administrator configured in your org to ensure Opportunity Close Dates that are entered are in the future.

To verify this, considering you are using lightning experience
go to the setup menu --> Object Manager tab --> Opportunity --> select Validation Rules in the left sidebar menu.

Scan through these and see if any of the error messages match the error message you are getting.

If you find one, then you can

1. deactivate the validation rule
2. import your Opportunities from other system
3. Reactivate Validation Rule

hope that helps